# Bootstrap CSS is not applied in weasyprint

Tags: python, css, flask, bootstrap-4, weasyprint

I have made a flask application which generates .pdf from html with weasyprint and send it as attachment. But apparently bootstrap 4 css is not applied. I can't find a solution. 
It is working well with pdfkit but I need weasyprint, since pythonanywhere.com does not support pdfkit.

I have tried linking bootstrap, using bootstrap css as file in my html, but there was no difference.

This is my python part, which generates and sends pdf.

```
@app.route('/pdf_send', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def pdf_send():

    rendered = render_template(
    'pdf_send2.html', 
    name=name_g, 
    surname=surname_g,
    email=email_g,
    address=address_g,
    invoice_no=invoice_no_g,
    dict_g=dict_g,
    bendra_suma_g = ('%.2f' % round(float(bendra_suma_g[0]), 2)),
    send=send_g,
    today=today_g
    )

    css_file = ('static/bootstrap.css')
    filename = 'SF-' + invoice_no_g +'.pdf'
    html = HTML(string=rendered)
    css = CSS(filename=css_file)
    html.write_pdf(filename, stylesheets=[css])
    send_email(filename, email_g)

    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: Have you tried reading in a local copy of bootstrap css and adding it manually as a giant string? Not saying it's efficient, but it would be a good troubleshooting step. I can't find documentation that indicates that external css files are directly supported.

http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#instantiating-html-and-css-objects

Comment: It is still the same result as before. Somehow weasyprint does not get along with with bootstrap.

Comment: Did you make sure there are no imports or other "modern" css features? That might be why it's no compatible. It seemed to me from the documentation that there are specific css features weasyprint explicitly supports, and that's it.

Comment: So I removed Bootstrap, but added custom css in same html. Couldn't make weasyprint to work together with Bootstrap.

Comment: I think the answer is that weasyprint is a bad idea. It seems extremely limited. I'd revisit the requirement of using it.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread but I stumbled over it while looking for an answer to the same question, so I'm adding my workaround in case it helps anyone else. I'm going to start by pointing out that although this does work Bootstrap really isn't intended to be used for printing, and weasyprint ignores anything inside a `@media` query so you're going to need to add a lot of css anyway in order to make it render correctly so it's probably not worth it.

Using the code from the original question, if you add the bootstrap cdn css to the `stylesheets` list it will render:

```
html = HTML(string=rendered)
css = CSS(filename=css_file)
html.write_pdf(filename, stylesheets=[css, "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"])
```

However, given the issues with Bootstrap rendering, I found this trick to be considerably more useful for applying fonts.

Comment: Which file is being refered in `css_file` variable? is it some custom css or a bootstrap local copy? Somehow I tried and it is not rendering as it should. `col-md*` classes not rendering properly.

Comment: @Volatil3 did you got `col-md*` printing properly to the PDF? If so, could you point to the solution?

Comment: Sorry, css_file is your custom css. Bootstrap is added in the stylesheets call.

I'm afraid I used custom CSS to get columns to be the correct size on the pdf. As it's always going to be the same size it doesn't need to be responsive (for my use case).

Answer (score 2):

weasyprint doesnt work well with bootstrap .

This is the reference [Link to Github site](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/270) for clarity.

Whatever bootstrap classes you write will be ignored by WeasyPrint.

You can see the "Ignored ..." messsages in WeasyPrint error log(if you ever initilised).

So its better to use CSS for the print-pages