# weasyprint is not rendering bootstrap4 css correctly

Tags: css, django, python-3.x, bootstrap-4, weasyprint

I'm trying to generate an invoice by first designing it as HTML and then feeding that to weasyprint to generate the pdf. I'm using Django 2.2.5 version with bootstrap 4.3.1 and weasyprint 50.
The `invoice_generator(request)` function calls the generate_invoice function with the `request`, `username` and `template_name`.

views.py:

```py
from invoice_generator import generate_invoice

def invoice_generator(request, username):
    ret_val = generate_invoice(request, username, template_name="ui/invoice.html")
    return ret_val
```

invoice_generator.py:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from commons.models import SMSUser, SMSMessages, Invoice
from commons.serializers import InvoiceSerialzer

from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse

from weasyprint import HTML, CSS
import tempfile

from datetime import datetime, date

def generate_invoice(request, username, template_name):
    user_to_invoice = SMSUser.objects.get(username=username)
    user_invoice = Invoice(invoice_to=user_to_invoice)

    company_to_invoice = user_to_invoice.company_name
    company_tin = user_to_invoice.company_tin
    account = user_to_invoice.pk
    user_email = user_to_invoice.email
    all_users_in_company = SMSUser.objects.filter(company_name=company_to_invoice)
    user_invoice.save()
    invoice_number = user_invoice.pk
    paid_status = user_invoice.payment_status

    all_sms_sent_by_users = {}

    for user in all_users_in_company:
        # TODO you can run the code at the begining of each month by doing:
        # TODO x = date.today() then x = x.replace(day=1) 
        total_sent_by_single_user = SMSMessages.objects.filter(
            sending_user=user,
            delivery_status="True",
            sent_date__year=datetime.now().year,
            sent_date__month = 10
            # sent_date__month = datetime.now().month - 2
            )
        all_sms_sent_by_users = {
            "all_sms_sent": [
                {
                "user": user,
                "total_sent_single_user": total_sent_by_single_user.count()
                }
            ]
        }
    total_amount_sent = SMSMessages.objects.filter(
        sent_date__year = datetime.now().year,
        sent_date__month = 10,
        # sent_date__month = datetime.now().month - 1,
        sending_user__company_name=company_to_invoice
    )

    # TODO feed the below object to a pdf renderer and return that pdf rendered object
    context_object =  {
        "username": user_to_invoice,
        "company_name": company_to_invoice,
        "account": account,
        "invoice_number": invoice_number,
        "tin": company_tin,
        "email": user_email,
        "bill_month": datetime.now().month - 1,
        "all_sms_sent": all_sms_sent_by_users,
        "total_amount_sent": total_amount_sent.count(),
        "vat": total_amount_sent.count() * 0.70 * 0.15,
        "total_price": total_amount_sent.count() * 0.70 * 1.15, 
        "payment_status": paid_status
    }

    rendered_html = get_template(template_name).render(
       context_object,
        request
    ).encode(encoding='UTF-8')

    pdf_file = HTML(string=rendered_html, base_url=request.build_absolute_uri())
    pdf_file.render()
    pdf_container = pdf_file.write_pdf(
        stylesheets=[
            CSS(
                'ui' + settings.STATIC_URL + 'ui/css/bootstrap.min.css'
            )
        ]
    )
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf;')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=Invoice ' + company_to_invoice + str(datetime.now().month) + '.pdf'
    response['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'UTF-8'
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True) as pdf_writer:
        pdf_writer.write(pdf_container)
        pdf_writer.flush()
        pdf_writer = open(pdf_writer.name, 'rb')
        response.write(pdf_writer.read())
    return response
```

and this is the `ui/invoice.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% load static %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'ui/images/favicon.ico' %}">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- bootstrap4 css -->
    <link href="{% static 'ui/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>sms.et | Invoice</title>
</head>
<body class="text-center d-print-block" style="background-color: #f5f5f5;">
    <div class="container-fluid align-items-center align-middle">
        <header>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 bg-primary">
                    <h1 class="font-weight-bold self-center h1 text-white">Service Invoice</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h4 class="font-weight-light self-center h4"><p>Customer Name: <span class="font-weight-lighter"> {{ username.company_name }}</span></p></h4>
                    <h4 class="font-weight-light self-center h4"><p>Account: <span class="font-weight-lighter"> {{ account }}</span></p></h4>
                    <h4 class="font-weight-light self-center h4"><p>T.I.N: <span class="font-weight-lighter"> {{ tin }}</span></p></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h4 class="font-weight-light self-center h4"><p>Invoice number: <span class="font-weight-lighter"> {{ invoice_number }}</span></p></h4>
                    <h4 class="font-weight-light self-center h4"><p>Email: <span class="font-weight-lighter"> {{ email }}</span></p></h4>
                    <h4 class="font-weight-light self-center h4"><p>Bill Month: <span class="font-weight-lighter"> {{ bill_month }}</span></p></h4>
                    <h4 class="font-weight-light self-center h4"><p>Due date: <span class="font-weight-lighter"> 5 days from this invoice</span></p></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
    <hr class="bg-primary">
    <h6 class="font-weight-lighter self-center h6"><p>Paid status: {{payment_status}}</p></h6>
    <hr class="bg-primary">

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="font-weight-light self-center h2">All users that sent sms:</label>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <!-- dict object all _sms_sent is garnered from the views and parsed accordingly as key & value of all_sms_sent.items -->
                        {% for key, value in all_sms_sent.items %}
                        <h4 class="font-weight-lighter h4">username</h4>
                        {% for val in value %}
                        <p>{{ val.user }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <h4 class="font-weight-lighter h4">Company</h4>
                        <p>{{ val.user.company_name }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <h4 class="font-weight-lighter h4">Total sent</h4>
                         <p>{{ val.total_sent_single_user }}</p>
                         {% endfor %}
                         {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h4 class="font-weight-light self-center h4">Total sms sent in the month:</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p>{{ total_amount_sent }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h4 class="font-weight-light self-center h4">Price per text:</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p>0.70 Birr</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h4 class="font-weight-light self-center h4">V.A.T:</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p>{{ vat }} Birr</p>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h4 class="font-weight-light self-center h4">Total:</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p>{{ total_price }} Birr</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="container-fluid align-items-center align-middle bg-primary">
        <footer>
            <div class="row text-white">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h4 class="font-weight-light self-center h4"><p>Address</p></h4>
                    <p class="quote font-weight-light center">Ethiopia, Addis Ababa, Kirkos sub-city, woreda 02,  House No. 700.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="{% static 'ui/images/logo.jpg' %}" width="50" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top navbar-brand" alt="">
                    <br>
                    <a href="www.sms.et" class="text-white blockquote">www.sms.et</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p class="quote font-weight-light center">Outstanding bill must be settled 5 days after issuance of this service invoice.</p>
                    <p class="quote font-weight-light center">Any questions can be forwared to us via our phone number: +251977207777</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that weasyprint is not rendering the bootstrap 4 css as expected, i.e. as written above.
This is a question [Bootstrap CSS is not applied in weasyprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496398/bootstrap-css-is-not-applied-in-weasyprint)
 that comes close to my problem but the solutions described made no difference.
Just to clarify, this is how it was supposed to look like (the html version):
[image: how it was supposed to look like].
But it ended up looking like this:
[image: first of two pages]
and this:
[image: second of two pages]
Can anybody please help?

### Edited to include urls.py of project and app

this is the urls.py from the project:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    # for the ui app
    path('ui/', include('ui.urls')),
]
```

and this is the urls.py for the ui app:

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "ui"

urlpatterns = [
    path('homepage/', views.homepage, name="homepage"),
    path('login/', views.login_request, name="login"),
    path('dashboard/<username>/', views.dashboard, name="dashboard"),
    path('logout/', views.logout_request, name="logout"),
    path('register/', views.register_request, name="register"),
    path('ajax/dashboard_update/', views.ajax_dashboard_update, name="ajax_dashboard_update"),
    path('<username>/invoice/', views.invoice_generator, name="invoice_generator"),
]
```

Comment: 1. are you sure your css file is located at  'ui/' + settings.STATIC_URL + 'ui/css/bootstrap.min.css'? (ui/static/ui/css/bootstrap.min.css I assume) 2. in your settings STATIC_URL = 'static/' right? slash only after keyword.

Comment: @engin_ipek thanks for you quick reply. As for question 1. Yes, I'm sure it's at 'ui' + settings.STATIC_URL + 'ui/css/bootstrap.min.css' (notice that I have removed the slash from the 1st ui). 2. while in settings STATIC_URL='/static/'.
Even after removing the slash from the 'ui', the problem presists.

Comment: Your welcome. Can you also share your urls.py as well pls? I still think it is about static config not about weasy

Comment: @engin_ipek I've editted the question to add the urls.py files of the project and app.

Comment: from django.conf import settings from django.conf.urls.static import static urlpatterns = [ # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ... ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL) add this to your projects urls.py

Comment: No, still the same, nothing changed.

Comment: I'm having the same problem (bootstrap4/weasyprint) with the funny rendering of all digits in the PDF

Comment: Did someone solve this issue? I got the same...

Comment: @PauloMarques sorry brother but no. I decided to scrap the whole pdf thing and leave it as html

Comment: @GaddBWeldesenbet Noticed some characteristics for weasyprint... Image width and height, for example. The weasyprint flow (I) allocate the space in pdf for the **original** image size, (ii) resize picture based on width and height, (iii) render the picture. Note that it should (I) resize, (ii) allocate (iii) render. For me, I just resize manually the picture for the size I wanted and used it as my "original"

Comment: @GaddBWeldesenbet, for my case yes... I just resized the image for the size I wanted before rendering anything...

Comment: @PauloMarques so it uses the original size of the images to render not the one found on the inputted html file...ok, I'll try it that way.

Much obliged

Comment: @GaddBWeldesenbet give me a feedback later if you can

Comment: @PauloMarques will do but it will take a while. As I previously said I decided to scrap the whole pdf thing and leave as html. It's currently in operation, I will do what you said when I start working on the upgrade. Again much obliged.